# maxima and minima piecewise function

Tags: functions, optimization

I'm exercising on maxima and minima, I think I got the point of global and local extremes but then I find this piecewise function where my teacher says that the right answer is "c". I thought the right answer was "b". Could you help me understand why,please.

Let $f(x)=  
\begin{cases}
1+x, &\text{if }x\lt 0\\
0,& \text{if }x=0\\
1-x,&\text{if }x\gt0
\end{cases}
$

Then:

**a)** f has a local, but not global, minimum point

**b)** f has a global minimum point

**c)** f has a local, but not global, maximum point

**d)** f has a global maximum point

Thank you

Comment: The special value at x=0 makes the function discontinuous. There is clearly no global minimum because the function is not bounded from below. There is an upper bound f(x)<1, but the value 1 is not reached, as f(0)=0 instead of 1 (which would be the left/right limit). Extrema are tricky for discontinuous functions, but strictly speaking, in the neighbourhood of x=0, all the values of the function are bigger than f(0), so in some weak sense, x=0 is a local minimum. That would make (a) the correct answer.

Comment: @iadvd You can use `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` for piecewise defined functions. (See the post.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak understood, thank you for making that change.

Comment: It might be useful to draw a picture: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bpiecewise%5B%7B%7B1-x%2Cx%3E0%7D%2C%7B1%2Bx%2Cx%3C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cx%3D0%7D%7D%5D%5D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question one has to review the [definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition). Specialized to this case these definitions read: A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a global maximum point at $x^∗ \in \mathbb R$ if $f(x^∗) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$.  Similarly, $f$ has a global minimum point at $x^∗ \in \mathbb R$ if $f(x^∗) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

Clearly, for the given function $f$ the following holds: for every $x^∗ \in \mathbb R$ there exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x^*) \lt f(x)$. This is the negation of the definition of the global maximum. So, $f$ does not have a global maximum. Similarly, $f$ does not have a global minimum.

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to have a local maximum point at the point $x^∗ \in \mathbb R$ if there exists some $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $f(x^∗) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in (x^*-\epsilon, x^*+\epsilon)$.  Similarly, $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to have a local minimum point at the point $x^∗ \in \mathbb R$ if there exists some $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $f(x^∗) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in (x^*-\epsilon, x^*+\epsilon)$.

It is clear that for $\epsilon = 1/2$ we have $f(0) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in (-1/2,1/2)$. Therefore, $f$ has a local minimum at $x^* = 0$.

It is a good exercise to state the negation of the statement: "$f$ has a local maximum" and prove it for the given $f$.

Finally, the correct answer is (a).

A graph is always helpful:

[image]